# Show each L,a,b component of L*a*b color space individually in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, colors

I want to segment Left ventricle from CT scan RGB Image by fuzzy c means after converting  my RGB image in L*a*b Color Space but not getting required Results.
i want to saw L, a and b component of this color space individually in Matlab. Can anybody help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with using `imshow` on each of the components?  I'm assuming you did something like this first:

```
rgb = imread('...'); %// Read in your image
cform = makecform('srgb2lab');
lab = applycform(im2double(rgb),cform);
```

[`makecform`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/makecform.html) creates a colour transformation structure, and we're choosing RGB to L*a*b*.  Next, we apply this colour transformation to convert our image with [`applycform`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/applycform.html).  Once you're done, do something like this:

```
figure;
for idx = 1 : 3
    subplot(3,1,idx);
    imshow(lab(:,:,idx), []);
end
```

This should show each component in a separate image in the same figure.  The first image is the `L` component, followed by the `a` then the `b` component.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Its work. can i give this lab varaible as an input in fcm function for fuzzy c means clustering. I gave lab as fcm first argument it gives an error

Comment: That function is not native to MATLAB. I can't comment on what you want done because I don't know how it works. Sorry.